# Where is the "Add" blend mode in Inkscape?

Tags: color, inkscape

How can I blend colors together with different blend modes in inkscape? I can't seem to find any options for controlling the method for blending colors.

For example, how could I make something like this:

[image]

In Inkscape using blend modes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Here's a way!

Create your objects, set your colors, then go to `Filter > Filter Editor`.

Now, create a new effect, then `Add Effect: Blend`. Drag the first connection to connect it to the `Source Graphic`. drag the other one to `Background Image`. Then enable it and in the `Effect parameters`, set the `Mode` to screen.

[image]

I this does not work there is a work around.

Assuming you kept your objects press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to bring up the Layers, change the `Blend Mode` to screen. You should now re-open `Filter Editor`, select the objects and enable the filter on those objects. You can now reset the Layer `Blend Mode` to Normal.

Here is a reference to [Compositing Filter](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-Compositing.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

## Improvement

The version posted by Samuel Dellicour works, but isn't actually using ADD, but instead SCREEN with appropriate sources. Its similar to an addition, but not exactly the same.

To get a true ADD effect swap the "Blend" effect for a "Composite" effect. Set the operator to arithmetic and K1/2/3/4 to 0/1/1/0. This will perform a true component-by-component addition.

[image]